# SWT TreeViewer is slow when filling with many elements

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I'm new in the java world, so I'm sorry if my question is trivial.

I'm developing a Eclipse view part, and I'm filling a SWT tree view with the following data structure. All data is in memory:

```
Node1
   Child1
   Child2
Node2
   Child1
   ...
   Child2915
```

I think that is not a very big tree, but it is slow being drawn (10 seconds). I have manage trees in .NET with more than 10.000 elements and it loaded smoothly. I don't know if I've implemented the code, but the same problem appeared in .NET if I did not call `BeginUpdate() - EndUpdate()`.

Must I call something similar in Java/SWT? Any other tips about why the tree is so slow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I used `setRedraw(boolean value)` after calling refresh in my TreeViewer.

```
public void refresh() {
    try {
        mTreeViewer.getControl().setRedraw(false);
        mTreeViewer.refresh(true);
        mTreeViewer.expandAll();
    }
    finally {
        mTreeViewer.getControl().setRedraw(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use the `SWT.VIRTUAL` flag when creating the Tree to help with the performance

For more information, see this article on [Virtual Trees and Tables](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-Virtual/Virtual-in-SWT.html)

This can also be combined with the JFace TreeViewer. See this article on the [JFace TreeViewer](http://eclipse.org/articles/Article-TreeViewer/TreeViewerArticle.htm) for more details (although this doesn't specifically mention the virtual flag)