# LabelProvider's cell.setImage() takes too long

Tags: java, swt, jface

I am developing an Eclipse RCP application plugin, and am having problems with a `TreeViewer` that at a certain point, has a Tree Item with very many sub-elements. In this case, it's 4000.

The `TreeViewer` has a `ContentProvider`, a `LabelProvider`, and an input(in this case, a modelprovider).

The `cell.setImage(...)` method inside the `StyledCellLabelProvider`s `update(ViewerCell cell)` method for 4000 elements takes more than a few seconds. I've tried skipping it and the 
`TreeViewer` has no problems...

I've also thought about doing the update in a separate thread, by calling:

```
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new UpdateItems(list));
```

And the Runnable...

```
private class UpdateItems implements Runnable {
        private List<Element> elementList;
        private UpdateItems(List<Element> elementList) {
            this.elementList = elementList;
        }
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("It's running!!!!");
                for (Element e : elementList) {
                    Signal s = (Signal) e;
                    s.setShowIcon(true);

                    s.updateElement(); //this calls an update on the item
                }
            }

    }
```

But this way, when I try to use the scroll to view the lower elements, the window freezes until done.

Is there any way to add a listener on the `TreeViewer` in order to fire a update when a `TreeItem` is visible? And by visible I mean that it is within sight of the user inside the current view, at the current place where it is scrolled (hope this makes sense).

Any support and opinions are appreciated!

Comment: What size are the images?

Comment: roughly 900 bytes each

Comment: And their dimensions?

Comment: 16x16 is the size of the icons

Comment: Are you using the equivalent of a [clip region](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipping_(computer_graphics))? Other [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595495/swt-treeviewer-is-slow-when-filling-with-many-elements)...even if you don't want direct access to what it's doing there should be a way to tell it what needs to be done.

Comment: Nope, not doing a clip region.